# Error for using cells() for string in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

So I am trying to use the Cells object to store a string and I keep getting an application error:

```
Sub analyze()
Dim rC As Integer
Dim rtData As Worksheet
Set rtData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RTN Data")
Dim finalSht As Worksheet
Set finalSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Final")
Sheets("Final").Cells(1, 1).Text = "order#"
finalSht.Cells(0, 2) = "Nurse"
finalSht.Cells(0, 3) = "Message"

rC = rtData.Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row



End Sub
```

Regardless of the different ways i keep trying to reference it

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.text is a read only property. Try assigning your value to .value

Also, cells are counted from 1, so cells(0,2) makes no sense.

```
Sheets("Final").Cells(1, 1).Value = "order#"
finalSht.Cells(1, 2) = "Nurse"
finalSht.Cells(1, 3) = "Message"
```

Comment: haha thank you very much...you solved all my problems right there, i was counting them from 0!

Comment: + Good catch. I completely missed the zero-based cell rows.

Answer (score 0):

The [Range.Text property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217.aspx) is the displayed text as it is formatted in a cell and you cannot assign it. Think of it as read only¹. Assign your string to the cell's [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) or (since .Value) is the default) just put it into the cell.

```
Sheets("Final").Cells(1, 1) = "order#"
Sheets("Final").Cells(1, 1).Value = "order#"
```

This can easily be demonstrated with dates. A cells might have a formatted .Text property of 18-Jul-2015, a date .Value of 07/18/2015 and a raw [Range .Value2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx) of 42203.

¹The official documentation for the .Text property is contradictory.

> Returns or sets the text for the specified object. Read-only String.

Either it is read only or you can set it. Not both.