# Excel VBA output a specific cells value

Tags: vba, excel

I can't seem to get something so simple to work in excel VBA

I have data on cell A1

```
Sub TestBox()
ActiveSheet.Activate
MsgBox (Cells(0, 0).Value)
End Sub
```

I want to output said data using basically a msgBox

> Run-time error:'1004' Application -defined or object-defined error

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why do you use `ActiveSheet.Activate`?  By definition, the `ActiveSheet` is the one that is active, so that seems to be a pointless piece of code.

Comment: I have no idea I guess i wanted to be implicit in describing which sheet I was using

Comment: If you want to be explicit in defining which sheet you are using, you should start your code with something like `Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet` and then use `MsgBox ws.Cells(1, 1).Value`.  If you don't, the user could change the active sheet between when you set the active sheet to be the active sheet and when the `MsgBox` is displayed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error for using cells() for string in vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489843/error-for-using-cells-for-string-in-vba)

Comment: I meant *explicit. I will start using this thanks so much :)

Answer (score 3):

A more reliable answer is to use something like this:

```
Sub TestBox()

Dim sVal as String
sVal = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1).Value
'sVal = ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Value 
'above can be used as well, but its not 100% reliable.

Msgbox sVal

End Sub
```

Notice how i explicitly declared my objects and I avoided Activate.

Comment: What is so bad with "ActiveSheet.Activate" anyhow?

Comment: **1)** `ActiveSheet.Activate` is redundant, since `ActiveSheet` already refers to the activated sheet. **2)** At any given point in the code the `ActiveSheet` may not be what you expect it to be. In this simple code you have in your question it won't throw an error or mess up your code, but it's good practice to avoid it unless absolutely needed (it's rare that it is, but at times it is). @Kagerjay

Comment: @Kagerjay ^^ and (unless I am completely confused - which is not unusual - and hopefully Scott will correct me if I am wrong) `Activate` (and `Select`) is quite slow in processing terms.

Comment: @YowE3K -- when used over and over yes. When used once or twice when needed, not so much.

Answer (score 1):

Cells are indexed at 1 as the initial value when referencing the entire sheet (as opposed to `ActiveCell.Offset`, those are indexed at 0)

`A1= Cells(1,1)`

so its

```
Sub TestBox()
ActiveSheet.Activate
MsgBox (Cells(1, 1).Value)
End Sub
```

to output the current sheet's A1 value